# SVG Browser problem

Tags: xml, svg

Hi 
can anyone can tell me why Chrome showing graph, but Firefox and Opera don't

```
val doctype = xml.dtd.DocType("svg", xml.dtd.PublicID("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN", "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"), Nil)

      val out = 
      
         
      

      xml.XML.save("result.xml", out, "UTF_8", true, doctype)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you output it? Lift? Do you have content type defined for the response?